# How to set spark.local.dir property from spark shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to set `spark.local.dir` from spark-shell using `sc.getconf.set("spark.local.dir","/temp/spark")`, But it is not working. Is there any other way to set this property from sparkshell.

Answer (score 12):

You can't do it from *inside* the shell - since the Spark context was already created, so the local dir was already set (and used). You should pass it as parameter when **starting** the shell:

```
./spark-shell --conf spark.local.dir=/temp/spark
```

Comment: In addition to your solution, can't he close the current spark context (using sc.stop()), and then set the spark.local.dir value, and sc.getOrCreate() it?

Comment: You're right - it would (might require a slightly longer version: `SparkSession.builder.config(sc.getConf).config("spark.local.dir","/temp/spark").getOrCreate()`) , but you get a `WARN SparkContext: Use an existing SparkContext, some configuration may not take effect`, which suggests this isn't the recommended path to take. But - yes, you're right, feel free to add as another answer.

Answer (score 4):

@Tzach Zohar solution seems to be the right answer.

However, if you insist to set spark.local.dir from spark-shell you can do it:

1) close the current spark context

```
    sc.stop()
```

2) updated the sc configuration, and restart it.

The updated code was kindly provided by @Tzach-Zohar:

```
SparkSession.builder.config(sc.getConf).config("spark.local.‌​dir","/temp/spark").‌​getOrCreate())
```

@Tzach Zohar note: "but you get a *WARN SparkContext: Use an existing SparkContext, some configuration may not take effect*, which suggests this isn't the recommended path to take.

Comment: From [Sparks' documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/configuration.html) section on `spark.local.dir`:  "NOTE: In Spark 1.0 and later this will be overridden by SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS (Standalone, Mesos) or LOCAL_DIRS (YARN) environment variables set by the cluster manager."